# How to disable a Field in redux-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I am simply trying to disable a field in `redux-form` as shown below but it does not seem to have any effect. This is `redux-form` version 7.4.2.

```
  <Field
    name="mu"
    type="text"
    component={renderField}
    label="DRIFT FUNCTION [ μ(X(t),t) ]:"
    disabled={true} 
    validate={[required]}
  />
```

Also

```
  <Field
    name="mu"
    type="text"
    component={renderField}
    label="DRIFT FUNCTION [ μ(X(t),t) ]:"
    props={{ disabled: true }}
    validate={[required]}
  />
```

Any help please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

input={{
       disabled: true,
   }}

add this to your Field tag

Comment: This had some side effects. I can no longer set values to the field via change(). Is there another way to disable the field?

Comment: this also hides the value of the field.

Answer (score 10):

You can pass the props object:

> **props : object [optional]**:
>   Object with custom props to pass through the Field component into a
>   component provided to component prop. This props will be merged to
>   props provided by Field itself.

```
// outside your render() method
const renderField = field => (
  <div>
    <input
      {...field.input}
      disabled={field.disabled} // you'll use it here
      type="text"
    />
  </div>
);

// inside your render() method
<Field
  name="myField"
  props={{
    disabled: true, // like this
  }},
  component={renderField}
/>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer! Like Edv Beq said, it is no longer possible to set values if the field ist not disables. So you cannot use  `input={{ disabled: true, }}` if you need set disabled by conditions.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, it works if you provide primitive react components rather than functions:

```
      <Field
        name="firstName"
        component="input"
        type="text"
        disabled={true}
        placeholder="First Name"
      />
```

[image: Edit Redux Form - Simple Example]

So I think the problem in your case is inside the `renderField` function you have not shown.

Comment: You don't need `disabled={true}` in case of "true" booleans. Putting just `disabled` is also ok.

Comment: I think `Field` just passes this (as any unknown prop) to the inner component.  HTML builtin components tags like `<input>` take a [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) attribute; custom `componend={...}` may take some else, or not support disabling at all...

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with redux-Form given code can work as @Vanun explained

```
<Field
    name="Name"
    component="fieldset"
    type="text"
    disabled={true}
  />
```